# What are commonly used gvim shortcuts?

Tags: c, vim

What are the most commonly used shortcuts used in gvim for C programming?  For instance, how can I perform function name auto completion (without using the default word autocomplete).  Could you please provide a cheatsheet or a tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use snipMate alot for C++/C programming:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

For function name auto completion you're probably stuck with ctrl+n ctrl+p or you can possibly try to get some omnicompletion working

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C%2B%2B_code_completion

Answer (score 1):

[This is what I was looking for](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html): a vim cheatsheet!